# Web API allow only single async task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

What is a proper scenario for handling only single async action? For example I need to import large file and while it being imported I need to disable that option to ensure that second import not triggered.

What comes in mind that:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImportConfigurationData()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Application["ImportConfigurationDataInProcess"] as bool? ?? false)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Task still running");

    HttpContext.Current.Application["ImportConfigurationDataInProcess"] = true;

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    //actual import

    HttpContext.Current.Application["ImportConfigurationDataInProcess"] = false;
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true)
}
```

But it seems like very hard-coded solution. What is a proper way of handling that?
Another thing it is not properly works on client side at it still waits for a response. So is it possible for user just to send that file to server and not wait unlit it will finishes  but reload page after file sent to server without waiting while `await` stuff will finish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) (as I explain on my blog). So you still just get one response per request.

The proper solution is to save a "token" (and import data) for the work in some reliable storage (e.g., Azure table/queue), and have a separate processing backend that does the actual import.

The `ImportConfigurationData` action would then check whether a token already exists for that data, and fault the request if found.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I am not going to change protocol. All I want start task somehow and send some error response if that request invoked while task still in process.

Comment: And I understand and can accept risks that comes with that solution. And I am not able to setup Azure only for that purpose. I tried Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => //Some import code); But it doesn't like async () after await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); and seems my task attached to the main thread

Comment: @Vladimirs: The point of my post is that `async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol. If you're using HTTP, then you only get one response per request. So if you want to return a response to the client before the import is complete, then you'll need a more complex solution. Azure is just one example of reliable storage; you don't have to use Azure to solve this.

Comment: so basically you suggest to store task state not in HttpContext.Current.Application but in DB. Or you mean to run the task on Azure as well?

Comment: @Vladimirs: Yes, a database is reliable storage, so that would be fine.